# direct description of $x$ is an integer such that $e^{-x}>1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Just a quick question guys! How do you give a more direct description of the following set and how do you get to that answer?

$$\Large S=\{x\in\Bbb Z:e^{-x}>1\}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $e^{-n}=\dfrac1{e^n}$, so $n\in S$ if and only if $\dfrac1{e^n}>1$. This is the case if and only if $e^n<1$. Now $f(x)=e^x$ is an increasing function of $x$, and $e^0=1$, so $e^n<1$ if and only if $n<0$. In other words, $S$ is the set of negative integers.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Recall that $e^x>1$ if and only if $x>0$.